# Can I have a menu item be a member of multiple menu groups?

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

Can I have a menu item be a member of multiple menu groups?

Such as...

```
<menu>
  <groupA>
    **<item1>**
    <item2>
    <item3>
    <item4>
  </groupA>
  <groupB>
    **<item1>**
    <item5>
    <item6>
  </groupB>
</menu>
```

I suspect this won't work because I will be declaring an i.d. for item1 twice.  Is the only way to duplicate the item1 but give them different i.d.'s?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**, you can put items in more than one group and use the same id for the same item.